# Кастомный сериализатор

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, сеть, serialize

У меня есть словарь такого типа

```
Dictionary<byte, object> parameters = new Dictionary<byte, object>();
```

В `object` я записываю данные типов `int, long, float` и тд

Мне нужно сериализовать этот список в массив байтов для передачи по сети. Но тут появляется проблема: как узнать какой тип находится в `object`? Есть идея записывать в массив байтов префикс из одного байта в котором будет указан тип переменной. Но для этого нужно сначала узнать какой тип находится в `object`, как-то сравнивать типы, все это сильно нагружает программу. Может быть у вас есть идеи как можно быстро и эффективно сериализовать этот словарь?

Сейчас у меня код примерно такой:

класс BinarySerializer

```
public static byte[] Serialize(short value) //получаю массив байтов
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
}
```

класс где происходит сериализация:

```
byte[] msg = new byte[256];

int offset = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<byte, object> pair in message.Parameters)
{
    msg[offset++] = pair.Key;

    byte[] array = new byte[0];
    byte [] buffer;
    if (pair.Value.GetType().Equals(typeof(short)))
    {
        msg[offset++] = 1; //тип переменной
        buffer = BinarySerializer.Serialize((short)pair.Value);
    }

    Buffer.BlockCopy (buffer, 0, msg, 0, buffer.Length);

    offset += buffer.Length;
}
```

Comment: [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) вернет тип, `BinarySerializer` это ваш класс?

Comment: Так в чем проблема? У вас же все работает...

Comment: Работает, но медленно. Если мне нужно отсылать каждые 100мс по 200 сообщений, и в каждом из них по 10 записей в словаре, то выходит очень накладно :(

Comment: @Grundy Да, это мой мой класс

Comment: @NickolayKabash, а зачем вообще кастить? а да, уже посмотрел

Comment: Оно автоматически не может привести к типу нужному, по сути я сам должен явно указать какую из перегрузок функции `Serialize` я должен вызвать

Comment: как вариант предлагают использовать рефлексию, но нужно замерять скорость

Comment: Сериализуемые типы данных гарантированно "простые"?

Comment: Да, простые типы. Но я бы хотел еще добавить пару других составных. Типа `Vector2(float, float)`

Comment: можно использовать [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо _BitConverter_

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` -  плохая идея, на выходе из примерно 100 байтов реальной длины данных будет около 1000, а то и больше

Comment: можно попробовать использовать _dynamic_: `public static byte[] Serialize(dynamic value)` и вместо object Тоже

Comment: была такая же идея, но мне нужно написать программу именно на платформе .NET 3.5, а там еще не было динамик

Comment: тогда можно попробовать рефлексию и замерить как быстрее с проверкой типов или с ней

Comment: Ну, учитывая всё выше написанное вам скорее всего придётся реализовывать свой аналог BinaryFormatter.  Особенно если хотите сериализовать/десериализовать свои/составные типы данных. Могу порекомендовать под декомпилятором глянуть на внтурянку этого класса, может что-то удастся скопипасить без лишних трудозатрат...

Comment: Хм, тут мысль пришла... А может сделать метод расширения для object и всех используемых вами типов данных? Предполагаю, что вызывая на конкретном экземпляре одного из типов упакованном в object ваш метод расширения компилятор может сообразить вызвать расширение для конкретного типа.

Comment: @Alexey можно и source  [BinaryFormatter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryformatter.cs,c19170bda56bc560) глянуть не обязательно декомпилировать :)

Comment: @Alexey, расширения, это всего лишь синтаксчический сахар над вызовом статических методов

Comment: @Grundy да я как-то всё забываю, что сорсы уже давно в открытом доступе. Всё по старинке через рефлектор смотрю....

Comment: @Grundy вобще да, расширения не вариант.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33079/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33088/discussion-on-question-by-nickolay-kabash--).

Comment: _"Dictionary<byte, object>();"_ -- это обязательно? если нет, то наверное, лучше не делать boxing значений, а сразу конвертировать.